# Are there open source deep parsers for English which take <tokens, POS tags> as input and produce the parse tree?

Tags: parsing, nlp, pos-tagger, parse-tree, part-of-speech

I'm wondering if there are open source probabilistic deep parsers for English which take as input a sequence of tokens and their corresponding parts of speech (POS tags) as input, and produce the parse tree as results. The parsers I am aware of take only token sequences as input, and produce as output the POS tags as well as the parse tree. In my case, I have a specific tokenizer and corresponding (hacked) POS tagger with Penn tagset already, and want to generate only the parse tree based on these tags and the corresponding tokens.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options: [BLLIP Parser](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/blob/master/first-stage/README#L192), [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#f), [Berkeley Parser](http://code.google.com/p/berkeleyparser/) ([Berkeley Parser tips](http://cackhanded.com/blog/post/2010/02/11/Tips-for-using-the-Berkeley-parser.aspx)), and probably others as well. Since all of these parsers do their own POS tagging, you may need to be careful about forcing them to use specific tags as it could cause parse failures. For example, BLLIP Parser will attempt to parse a sentence with tag constraints but will reparse without them if the parse fails.

Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of BLLIP Parser and have also worked on Stanford CoreNLP.